# How will coroutine behaves when the promise is resolved multiple times and co-routine have next yield

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, es6-promise, yield-keyword

For promise & co-routine, I've used bluebird npm package in NodeJs.

Can someone please help in understanding the behavior of below code when promise is getting resolved multiple times.

**Question:**

1. What will happens to coroutine when the promise resolved for multiple times?
2. Will the second yield will be affected by the multiple yield of first.

   const bluebird = require("bluebird");

   ```
   function func1() {
       return new bluebird((resolve, reject) => {
           let c = 0;
           let iterval = SetInterval(() => {
               c++;
               let cc = c;
               console.log(`c=${c}`);
               if(cc === 20) {
                       clearInterval(interval);
               }
               resolve(true);
           }, 1000);
       });
   }

   let run1 = bluebird.coroutine(function*() {
       try {
           yield func1();
           yield func1();
           yield func1();
           yield func1();
       } catch (e) {
           console.dir(e);
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Nothing. `resolve` and `reject` are issued as a pair of anonymous functions by the promise constructor. Once  one of them has been called, further call to either of them are *ignored*.

   Note new interval timers are called each time `func1` is called, without stopping those previously started, so expect the console output to look messy.

   Also each call to `func1` returns a different, new promise.
2. No because the postulate is incorrect. The first yield does not yield multiple times, it returns a promise that is resolved after one second. It's in a generator function, which resumes at the line after the previous yield (the last time I checked). The coroutine is about calling the generator function after the promise returned in the previous yield becomes settled. See http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After the promise is resolve for the first time then the co-routine will move to the next line for execution and the then the resolve will not have any impact or memory lea?

Comment: Short answer, yes. The coroutine would not be keeping references to the promise, just calling the then method of each promise as it is yielded. You should not keep an _ever growing, permanent_ list of promise objects or their resolve/reject functions any more than you would keep such a list of anything - it's a memory leak by another name.